# Amazon get merchant ID by signing in to seller central

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm developing an application that handles Amazon sellers data.
I don't want the seller to give me his merchant ID for getting his data from MWS API.
As I saw in other applications, they provide a link directly to the "Accept the Amazon MWS License Agreement to give access to my Amazon Seller Account with MWS".
Can anyone help me how I should do this?

Comment: I think Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask such kinds of questions. Refer to their official documentation for more help [Amazon MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I got it. there is MWS service- IRP, It is not readily available to everyone. You have to contact MWS Support and convince them to set you up for it .